# What is the equivalent of TT's RETURN directive in the Mojolicious renderer?

Tags: perl, rendering, mojolicious

In Template Toolkit there's the [`RETURN`](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template.html#section_RETURN) directive which can be used to stop processing the current template and return to the template from which it was called. How can I do this in Mojolicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based [on the documentation](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Template) saying *templates work just like Perl subs (actually they get compiled to a Perl sub internally)* I did some experiments. It appears that a simple

```
% return;
```

returns from a template discarding all its output. And

```
% return $_M;
```

returns from a template and keeps all its output generated before the return statement.

Please note that these are unofficial hacks. To find more possibilities to interact with Mojolicious internals you can try

```
% use Data::Dumper; return Dumper $self;
```

in your template and see the output and discover pretty much everything that is happening in the compiled templates.